# Retrieving LinearLayouts using their ID

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have an **8x8 board** with **64 four fields**, each being a **LinearLayout**.

Each **LinearLayout** has its ID like (field1, field2... field64). 
Now I want to modify the background of each field later in my program but I don't know how to retrieve the layout I want to modify. I wanted to put all of them in the Array but it's not working.

```
private LinearLayout[] fields = new LinearLayout[65];
this.fields[field_id].setBackgroundColor(colour);
```

Another approach:

```
for (int i=1; i<65; i++) {
       findViewById(R.id.field+i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

It does not work as well (obviously). How should I approach this?

Comment: Do you really need to reference them by ids? You can get all of them from their common parent. I think it's much better than dealing with set of ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them to a list, like this:

```
List fieldList = new ArrayList(64);
fieldList.add(R.id.field1);
fieldList.add(R.id.field2);
fieldList.add(R.id.field3);
// etc.
fieldList.add(R.id.field64);
```

Or use any other method to create such a list/array. It is a bit tedious, adding all fields like this, but it provides a usable list that can be used in loops.

It is also possible (I *think*), to renumber the ids of the fields (in `R.java`). If you make them subsequent, you can use the method you tried in the example code of your question. I do not not for sure whether these IDs stay the same when `R.java` is re-generated... If not, this method is not usable!

Answer (score 0):

Make an Array with your ids.

```
int[] ids = {R.id.field1,R.id.field2...}

for (int i=0; i<ids.lenght; i++) {
findViewById(ids[i]).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

OR

```
ViewGroup viewgroup = findViewById(R.id.parentview);

for(int i = 0; i < viewgroup.getChildCount();i++)
{
View child = viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access them this way, a tiny bit slower but doubt you will have a problem with it:

```
for (int i=1; i<65; i++) {
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier("field" + i, "id", getPackageName())
  findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(...);
}
```

Sounds like a lot of work adding them in xml(I assume?) like that though. Preferably you would add them by code and then just save them in an array.